# running program inside a loop in Stata

Tags: loops, stata

I am trying to run a program inside a loop, but I am getting

```
-Break--
r(1);
```

Here is my script:

```
 clear all
    forvalues i=1/5{
    sysuse auto if rep78==`i'
    capture program drop testpro
    program define testpro,eclass
    preserve 

    tabstat price mpg headroom,stat(mean) save
    mat avg=r(StatTotal)
    ereturn post avg
    restore 
    end
    }
    --Break--
    r(1);

    end of do-file

    --Break--
    r(1);
```

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues here. For one, you can't `sysuse` with an `if` clause, unlike with `use`.

There's no need to re-define a program with each iteration of the loop. Define it, then loop.

I am also not sure why you need a program, but this is a matter of taste or perhaps this is merely a pedagogical example.

The command `estadd` in the code below is part of `estout` suite from SCC.

```
clear all

capture program drop testpro
program define testpro, eclass
tabstat price mpg headroom, stat(mean) save
quietly estadd matrix avg = r(StatTotal), replace
end

forvalues i=1/5 {
    sysuse auto, clear
    keep if rep78==`i'
    testpro
    matrix list e(avg)
}
```

Comment: Yes, I do need a program in my problem. Thanks a lot!